# How do I convert $http.post response to $resource?

Tags: angularjs

I want to convert $http.post response to $resource. Any idea how do I achieve this?

http post json should be converted to $resource. I tried that but not sure how to achieve it.

Here is my code..

```
$http.post(base_url+"search",data).success(function(response){
    return $resource(response);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Search = $resource(base_url+"search", {}, {
        'query': {
            method: 'POST',
            isArray: false
        }
    });
    var search = new Search();
    search.$query(data).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$http.post(base_url+"search",data).success(function(response){
    console.log(response);
});
```

May be changed to(try this)

```
 var Search = $resource(base_url+"search", {}, {
        'query': {
            method: 'POST',
            isArray: false
        }
    });
    var search = new Search();
    search.$query(data).then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
```